# How to animate float:left divs?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

So I have a series of float:left div elements in a toolbar in my web-app. One of them, when clicked, expands to the right via a jQuery sliding animation. All the divs to the right of this div should slide over to make room for its increased size, but instead they jump to their new position to make room, then jump back when I shrink it again. How can I fix this to a smooth slide?

I think I need .animate(), but I can't figure out how to do without changing to position: absolute, which I don't want to use.

Comment: Please post your code and a jsFiddle if possible.

Comment: There's as much pertinent code as I can fit...the project is rather large.

Comment: I removed the code, I think it's extraneous here-- the problem is clear enough. Place some `<divs>` in a row with `float:left` and try increasing the width of one via jQuery animate and see how they all jump out of the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand you but my guess was that:

http://jsfiddle.net/QvCyx/

```
 $('#contrast').click(function () {
     var w = $('#contrastSlider').width();
     $('#contrastSlider').toggle("slide", 300);
     $('#about').animate({
         'margin-left': -w
     }, 300, function () {
         this.style.marginLeft = 0;
     });
 });
```

**UPDATE**

Here's the whole thing:
http://jsfiddle.net/CPR7R/

```
 $('#contrast').click(function () {
     var cs = $('#contrastSlider'),
         w = cs.width();
     if (!cs.is(':visible')) {
         $('#about').css('margin-left',-w);
         w = 0;
     }
     cs.toggle("slide", 300);
     $('#about').animate({
         'margin-left': -w
     }, 300, function () {
         this.style.marginLeft = 0;
     });
 });
```

**Second UPDATE**

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/EpCpr/

```
$('#container').on('click', '.slideTriggerer', function () {
    var that = $(this),
        sliderA = that.siblings('.slideA'),
        sliderB = that.siblings('.slideB'),
        defml = parseInt( sliderB.css('margin-left') ),
        w = sliderA.outerWidth();
    if (!sliderA.is(':visible')) {
        sliderB.css('margin-left', -w+defml);
        w = defml;
    }

    sliderB.animate({
        'margin-left': -w+defml
    }, 300, function () {
        sliderB.css('margin-left', defml);
    });
    sliderA.toggle("slide", 300);
});
```

Comment: It works one way only but the idea is obvious

Comment: You understood perfectly, that is exactly correct.

Comment: Could you help me understand how this works? I've gone through it a few times and can't completely work it out.

Comment: Sure. You get the width of `#contrastSlider` that is `w`. Then check what is the state of `#contrastSlider`. Is it not visible? If it's not the animation of `#about margin-left` should go from `-w` to `0` so it flows like the `toggle` on `#contrastSlider`. The other way around is from `0` to `-w` when  `#contrastSlider` is hiding. When the animation is finished the margin is reset to `0`

Comment: I understand! The other thing, though, is that I got so excited to have a partial solution I forgot about the other half. There's not just the one slider-- there's a whole row of icons that work this way, and if one is open and I open another, the first one needs to close. The point is there's a lot of sliding around going around, and I can't just write custom functions for each one, that would take forever. Is there not a way to just animate them floating left without manipulating all the margins of each affected element?

Comment: Why not it's not big deal. Just check element for the default value of `margin-left` it might not be `0` and use that value when resetting. Make the function taking a 2 sliding nodes as parameters and invoke it on them.

Comment: See the second update